# SSIS 2008: Illegal characters in path when trying to rename a file

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis-2008

I have a task that should rename a file

I have a variable called RenameFileName

```
\\servername\csv\BACKUP\" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + ".csv
```

When I run the task I get the error

```
Illegal characters in path
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Below are a list of the variables I have tried

```
\\\\servername\\csv\\BACKUP\\" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + ".csv

\\servername\csv\BACKUP\" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + ".csv

"\\servername\csv\BACKUP\" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + ".csv"

"\\\\servername\\csv\\BACKUP\\" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + ".csv"
```

Please note that the following works:

```
\\\\servername\\csv\\BACKUP\\ABC.csv
```

This however does not work

```
\\\\servername\\csv\\BACKUP\\"+1+".csv
```

It errors as soon a I put in double quotes. Single quotes are fine and they get put in the filename

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're missing double-quotes in the beginning and end of your code above, not sure if that's just a copy / paste mistake though?

Comment: I have added double quotes, escaped everything etc but it still errors.

Comment: Can you please provide in the question the full current variable you're using?

Comment: @J.D. I have added some more failures

Comment: "\\\\servername\\csv\\BACKUP\\" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + ".csv"
 
Works for me.  Note the leading and trailing quotes.  Normally when doing these expressions I do it section by section so if it breaks I know where.


FYI the expression 
    \\\\servername\\csv\\BACKUP\\"+1+".csv 
doesn't work because you're not casting the 1 as a string. and the leading and trailing quotes are missing.

    "\\\\servername\\csv\\BACKUP\\"+"1"+".csv" works

Comment: @Bee_Riii Might want to post that as an answer so you can get the credit. It looked good to me too, but I don't have SSIS setup on my test environment to be able to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

```
\\\\servername\\csv\\BACKUP\\" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + ".csv
```

You almost had it here but you missed the leading and trailing quotes.

```
\\servername\csv\BACKUP\" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + ".csv
```

Now you're missing the leading and trailing quotes and you failed to escape your back slashes.

"\servername\csv\BACKUP" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + ".csv"

Now you've got the quotes but not escaping the backslashes

"\\servername\csv\BACKUP\" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + ".csv"

This works correctly for me in SSIS expression.

[image: correctly working]

FYI
\\servername\csv\BACKUP\"+1+".csv

again you are missing the leading and trailing quotes.  However this won't work because it sees 1 as an integer and you need to convert it.

```
"\\\\servername\\csv\\BACKUP\\"+"1"+".csv"
```

The above works.

Normally when doing these sorts of expressions I do it iteratively.  Adding 1 piece to the expression at a time so if it breaks I know where it broke.  Remember you can click "evaluate expression" to see the result.

If the expression evaluates correctly but the package doesn't work then it would be another issue with the package.